# How to calculate simple CDF like Wolfram Alpha, but locally?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I received this great answer, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67090/statistical-significance-of-conditional-probabilties/67115?noredirect=1#67115, to my question about how to calculate the significance of conditional probability equations. They explained HDI was calculated by a binomial distribution cdf. I need an Unix-based program which will calculate the binomial distribution CDF for HDI. (I tried R but its `pbinom` function only gives p values. Which I suppose p-values can be equally useful in comparison.)

Comment: Please don't spread your question over two sites: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18189943/1412059

Comment: @Roland i thought this question was unique enough asking for a program which does it rather than a programming technique to warrant a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, `pbinom()` is the CDF function for the binomial distribution. I guess you are saying that what you actually want is the inverse of this, the quantile function. This can be found in `qbinom()`.

There is also `dbinom()` for the binomial PDF, and (although I'm sure you don't need it) `rbinom()` for random number generation from a binomial distribution.